# MongoRepository paging request returning incorrect data

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I have a simple paging request over Spring MongoRepository but MongoRepository apparently starts sending incorrect result after some arbitrary high page#. I am posting here to know if I am missing something or this could be a bug with Spring MongoRepository.

In my test i have 14 elements in my test mongo db and below paging requests works fine (retrieves data if its there):
`pageSize: 10, page#: 0 to 1073741823` 
But below page request returns me 10 entities from my mongoDB which i am not expecting:
`pageSize: 10, page#: 1073741824`

The breaking point is diff for diff combination of pageSize. Can share if require.

Below the libraries i am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Repository definition:

```
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And using this Repository as below:

```
public Page<SomeEntity> getSomeEntitiesByPage(int pageIndex, int paseSize, Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortQuery) {

    Pageable pageableRequest = new PageRequest(pageIndex, pageSize);

        return someEntityRepository.findAll(pageableRequest);

}
```

Comment: In your example you have only 14 records, but you claim to query for 'pageSize: 10, page#: 0 to 1073741823'. What exactly is '1073741823' - can you be more specific?

Comment: @R4J: so in the example, page# 0 and 1 returns 10 and 4 entities respectively. And pages 2 to 1073741823 returns no content i.e. `page.hasContent() = false` as expected. But surprisingly for page# 1073741824 to Integer.MaxValue it returns 10 entities, which it should not.

Comment: Wow.. this is very interesting. I just tried the same thing with my spring-data-mongodb application and it happened same for page# 1073741824 or higher. I guess spring data resets the page# to 0 for any value greater than 1073741824. I am definitely going to dig more and i will post what i find.

Comment: Just realized that 1073741824 is equal to 1GB and = 2^30. Based on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/ there is a limit on Maximum Number of Documents in a Capped Collection, which is 2^32, which 4 times what the limit we are hitting here.

Comment: Jira has been filed and turns out to be issue with library where they are trying to get the offset by `Pageable.getOffset()` with return type as int and that gets wrapped around to a negative value. [Jira reference](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Spring MongoRepository and the Jira has been filed for the same. MongoRepository is trying to get the required offset `Pageable.getOffset()` with return type as int and when `pageNumber*pageSize > Integer.MaxValue` it gets wrapped around as a negative offset causing the 1st page to be retrieved. Jira reference for this can be found [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1223)